# Number of container in Yarn is different with setting

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am using Hadoop 2.9.0 with Yarn. My cluster has 4 nodes (3 slaves and 1 both master and slave), each of them has

- 8Gb RAM
- 8vCores

So, totally my cluster has 32Gb RAM, and 32vCores.

When I run Hadoop streaming, the Yarn display information as follows:
[image]
Here is my configuration

- hdfs-site.xml
  [image]
- yarn-site.xml
  [image]
- mapred-site.xml
  [image]

My input file is 151Mb, and I set dfs.blocksize=4Mb

So, I have several questions:

1) From other topics, I know that the number of mappers should equal the number of splits, which is 151/4=38. And 1 container contains only 1 mapper, so there should be 38 containers.However from the picture, just only 1 container, so just only 1 mapper is performing. Where I got wrong?

2) If I wrong, how the number of container is calculated?

3) Yarn only shows number of containers, how can I know number of mappers and reducers for the application I am running?

I have read around but still can not understand those things since I am now to Yarn and Hadoop. Please help.

Comment: Why is your blocksize only 4MB? If you need something that small, I don't think Hadoop is well suited for your dataset. Reason being - One could process a 151MB text file in a few seconds on a single machine.

Comment: You're right. I want to validate my research using parellel method with Hadoop. Because the resource is limited, I can use only several computers. And I use that database as an example to illustrate my method. But the problem is even with that small database, it took too long to finish. So, I think I got wrong at some setting.

Comment: Database? You mean input file? And yes, attempting to split a relatively small file into 4MB pieces and perform any operation on it will probably take a long time. You can start *with multiple threads* to perform parallel operations, not *multiple computers*. For example, use Spark's master `local[*]` setting

Comment: Yeah, I mean input file. I think that the smaller I split the file, the more parellel the processing will be, the faster the process is. Is it not right? My purpose is to run MapReduce on Hadoop. So I am not going to use Spark. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Splitting a file so small only causes so much optimizations... You need to spin up a Java process for each split, which causes extra overhead. Also, if the file is not splittable (such as a ZIP file), your blocksize doesn't matter

Comment: FWIW, working in Hadoop for 3 years, I find more people writing Spark than Mapreduce.